# Is it safe to save "Web Client Secret" of "Google Sign in" in Firebase on a android project?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

This is how I retrieve the Web Client Secret which is store in string.xml

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setClientSecrets(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id), 
getString(R.string.cl_sc))
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .build();
```

Comment: Not a good idea, probably load that from the config file and maintain that in the server.

Comment: How can I possibly do that if I'll be using that while getting some information of google account whenever a user sign in?

Comment: Naveen is right. Storing client secrets in the app is a terrible idea.

Comment: I agree with you guys, is there other way to retrieve it like what R.string.default_web_client_id which is already exist in resources out of nowhere?